# Application logging and information analysis

Tags: c#, .net, sql, logging, data-mining

I am currently trying to add some logging information to a C# application to be able to understand in what part of the appplication most of the user are spending their time. I am planning to send all those informations to a sql server and intent to do some report.

I would like to know if some of you have some experience or tips to share about the subject. What is the best database schema to do those kind of things, things to do, things to avoid.

Thank you

Comment: I think the database schema really depends on how your app works and looks, what you should actually look support for is the approach on how to do it (which will in the end shed some light into the underlying schema).

Answer (score 1):

log4net is a good logging tool, it can log to a file and i believe to a database.

Comment: Sounds interesting but what should I use to do the reporting. How should my database be strutured to be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise Library provides a logging provider as well as scripts to install a default logging database schema.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569(v=PandP.50).aspx